# Can't install Ubuntu, GRUB stage1.5read error... new to ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot

ok so i have been struggling with this for the whole day now and i really need help. im new to ubuntu but i cant even get off the floor with it this is an install problem the OS works fine from the CD but doesnt transfer to the drive. these are the details:

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.4, didn't work had read errors from the drives I tried it on. I tried using an older version because I have old tech in this comp. That didnt work either same issue.

Finally got somewhere because of that though. The older version used a different resolution and I was able to see the word "RUB" infront of the read error. This lead to finding out some common error's with reading disks called GRUB errors. But all the internet posts spoke of numbers affixed to these I didnt have any.

So my brother hinted at a bit of software a thing called 'ultimate boot cd' to try and fix these issues. The software when booting from CD didn't really work the way intended but lead me to a number:

```
GRUB loading stage1.5read error
```

All of the other online articles are useless as they start talking about things I dont understand (being new to linux) and relatively new to coding in general.

Comment: Did you know that you can *edit* your question whenever you want to? So you don't need to create several post for one problem.

Comment: i did but i felt this needed a new one with more up to date info!

Comment: So this are two different problems, right?

Comment: one problem that has evolved

Comment: not a duplicate just a similar problem that i wanted to re upload with all the new info ill take the old one down if i can.